# Start activity inside ViewFlipper or a layout

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have a layout with tabs on top (added programmatically) and ViewFlipper under with 3 different views one of which contains a ListView. And I have 2 activities, one is the primary one that creates the tabs and one that dowloads some data and displays it in a new ListView. What I would like to do is start the second activity from the first one and display the data in the ListView that is inside ViewFlipper. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing may be easier to achieve using **fragments**, or by putting the second activity into the ViewFlipper completely.

See the [Android Developer site here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for information on utilising fragments:

Comment: It works with fragments, but now there is another problem. I have a GestureDetector that navigates the ActionBar(tabs) and now it doesn't work.